# Data Exchange - Change Units to Imperial For Element Parameters From GraphQL

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

When I use Autodesk's Data Exchange graphql API to get properties from objects in a Data Exchange, it uses metric units by default. Can I add something to the query to have the API return values in Imperial units?

Here is an example of a graphql query I am using. Currently, parameters like "Length" are being returned in Meters.

```
query getQuantityTakeoff ($exchangeId:ID!) {
  exchange(exchangeId: $exchangeId) {
    id
    name
    version {
      versionNumber
    }
    elements {
      results {
        id
        name
        properties {
          results {
            name
            value
            propertyDefinition {
                description
                specification
                units
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is an example of what I am being returns

```
...
                  "name": "Volume",
                  "value": 5.663369318399997,
                  "propertyDefinition": {
                    "description": "Length x Cross Section Area",
                    "specification": "Volume",
                    "units": "Cubic meters"
                  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

At current stage it is not possible, but there are plans to add the possibility to give the option of requesting results using needed measuring system (metric or imperial).
My educated guess is that at the moment you get the units based on the region:

- If your hub is in EMEA region, then you will get metric results.
- If it is located in US, then your results will be imperial.